# How can i find the exact process name/address instead running over all the processes?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 top i did:

```
Process[] hProcessSnap;
Process hProcess = null;
hProcessSnap = Process.GetProcesses();
```

Then in the constructor i did:

```
for (int n = 0; n < hProcessSnap.Length; n++)
            {
                if (hProcessSnap[n].ProcessName == "test")
                    hProcess = hProcessSnap[n];
            }
```

But when i look at the processes list the hProcessSnap variable i see for example:
Two processes of the firefox mozilla browser.

00001B00-FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_168.exe

And the second one is:

00001C5C-FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_168.exe

I can find them manualy but is this the name of the process ? 
What i see in the list of processes in hProcessSnap is in two different places: FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_168

So how i find in between the two processes names which one is the first and which one is the second ? In firefox/mozilla the first one is 00001B00-FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_168.exe

But in my list i get only names.
I need to find somehow which is the first process and which is the second. In the list they both have the same name.

EDIT**

This is an example of how i want to get/see the list of the processes:

http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&id=4tHcmKOjlaCtmK6S5aXJ1afO5co

EDIT**

Better image:

http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&id=4tHcmpymlZ-pm6WSz6We4qfO5co

Comment: Ondrej i guess in the List the first that appears. The problem is that in the list i get two same exact names without the address in the beginning like: 00001C5C-FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_168.exe All i get is : FlashPlayerPlugin_11_8_800_168 twice.

Comment: Are you asking how you differentiate between the two processes?  They will have different Id's

Comment: Edited my question added link to the image of how i want to see/get the list of processes. And then select the process according to the address near it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Name` property is always the filename of the process minus the `.exe` suffix.

To get the actual filename of a process, you can do this:

```
string strFilename = Path.GetFileName(hProcessSnap[n].MainModule.FileName);
```

But the following will always return the same value, too:

```
string strFilename = hProcessSnap[n].Name + ".exe";
```

If you want it in the exact format as you're saying (including PID), do this:

```
Process proc = hProcessSnap[n];
string strProcessListName = proc.Id.ToString("X8") +
  "-" + proc.Name + ".exe";
```

Comment: Angelo this line: string strFilename = Path.GetFileName(hProcessSnap[n].MainModule.FileName); give me exception: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process

Comment: Yes, you also have to deal with that for the first code snippet. If you just want to access the filename and not rely on multiple machine infrastructures, then just append `.exe` to the end of the `Name` property, works just as well.

Comment: Edited my question added link to the image of how i want to see/get the list of processes. And then select the process according to the address near it.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to differentiate between the processes?

If you are letting a user select a process then you need to find which process they selected based on process.Id.  How you display this to the user and go between ProcessName and Id is all dependent on your UI choices for your application.

```
for (int n = 0; n < hProcessSnap.Length; n++)
{
    // ProcessName is not Unique, there could be many matching processes
    //   and this loop will only return the last one.
    if (hProcessSnap[n].ProcessName == "test")  
        hProcess = hProcessSnap[n];
    // Id is Unique - there will be only one matching process
    if (hProcessSnap[n].Id == 123)
        hProcess = hProcessSnap[n];
}
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry I couldn't see the images you uploaded.  The basics of any UI will be this...  You need to bind your listbox to the Process.Id, Display the Process.ProcessName to the user for them to select a Process, then when you need to actually manipulate (delete / etc) the process you need to find it by Process.Id.

Comment: Edited my question added link to the image of how i want to see/get the list of processes. And then select the process according to the address near it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result simply with LINQ;

```
  Process hProcess = Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "test").OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

You may want a different condition in your `Where` clause but this is the basic idea. First filter on the process name. Then order by the start time so you can figure out which one began first. `FirstOrDefault()` is going to return the first item in the collection or `null` if there are no items.

Comment: Edited my question added link to the image of how i want to see/get the list of processes. And then select the process according to the address near it.

Comment: @DoronMuzar I can't really see that image but I don't really know where you're going with it anyways.. You're trying to select a process programatically, right? If you put the process name you're looking for in the `Where(x => x.ProcessName == "process I'm looking for")` then this will select the most recently started process with that name.